# Using cordovaplugin to add a javascript interface which can access java-methods synchronously

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, cordovawebview

I am currently developing a cordova-plugin which has methods which have to be accessed synchronously in the following fashion. (I ***know*** that the absolute best and "right" way to do this is with callbacks. But because of backwards compatibility and demands that I ***cannot*** change it has to be this way.)

In javascript:

```
result = plugin.method();   
dostuffwith(result);
```

After loads of googling and SO I have thought of implementing it by calling my native code on deviceready, adding a JSInterface to the cordova webview with:

```
JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(cordova.getActivity(), plugin);

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
```

and then calling the methods from there afterwards with:

```
result = window.JSInterface.method();
```

Now comes the question, how do I access the webview in cordova from my plugin so that I can do this?

Thank you for any answers that do not include "Use callbacks".